# Infinite series converges using limits

Tags: limits, convergence-divergence

Do the following series diverge?

$$A=\sum^{\infty}_{n=1} \frac{e^n}{n}, B=\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}\frac{n^{1337}}{10^n}$$

**Official Solutions**:

- $A$ does not converge since $\lim \frac{e^n}{n} $ as $n \rightarrow \infty = \infty$ and exponentials are stronger than powers.
- $B$ converges, and they checked this by using the quotient test: $$ \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{\frac{(n+1)^{1337}}{10^{n+1}}}{\frac{n^{1337}}{10^n}} = \frac{1}{10} < 1$$ hence it converges.

**My Question**

For $B$, can I say it converges with the same reasoning as $A$ ? (i.e. $B$ converges because its limit would be $0$), or when should I use limits to solve series (not talking about the tests btw, but a direct limit)?

Comment: You cannot just look at the limit to test convergence.  The harmonic series.... the limit of $1/n$ is zero, but the sum diverges.

Comment: The Divergence Test can only let you conclude a series diverges. It can never let you conclude a series converges. It is not the same reasoning: in the first one, we say "If the terms do not go to $0$, then the series diverges." You want to argue "If the terms go to zero, then the series converges." They are not equivalent statements. Compare "If I fall into the pool, then I will get wet" with "If I don't fall into the pool,, then I will remain dry." The first one is true, but the second need not be true (you could get caught in a rainstorm, for instance...)

Comment: thanks for the amswer, I have another question, if I want to solve a normal limit f(x), can I use the convergence tests?

Comment: Is a "normal limit" a series? Convergence tests are test to see whether a series converges. The are for series, nit for whatever-you-decide-to-use-them-for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A series with terms $\{ a_{n} \}_{n=1}^{+\infty}$ which is convergent must satisfy the necessary, but not sufficient, condition $a_{n} \to 0$. A possible proof for this fact is to observe that
$$
a_{n}=\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_{k}-\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}a_{k} \quad \forall n \geq 2.
$$
Since the two partial sums converge to the same limit we have that $a_{n}\to 0.$ The series $A$ in your example does not satisfy the condition $a_{n}\to 0,$ thus it is not convergent.
As for you question about the ratio test I suggest you a rule of thumb; when you are using the ratio test or the root test you are implicitly comparing your series with a geometric series. For example, let us call the coefficients of the second series $\{ b_{n} \}_{n}$ then
$$
\frac{b_{n+1}}{b_n}\to \frac{1}{10} \quad n \to +\infty.
$$
So there will be a certain index $n_{0}$ such that
$$
\frac{b_{n+1}}{b_n} \leq \frac{2}{10} \quad \forall n \geq n_{0} \tag{1}.
$$
From the condition $(1)$ you can easily prove by induction that
$$
b_{n_{0}+k} \leq b_{n_{0}}\cdot (\frac{2}{10})^{k} \tag{2}.
$$
From condition $(2)$ you obtain an estimate from above of your series
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty}b_{k}\leq \sum_{k=1}^{n_{0}} b_{k} + \sum_{k=n_{0}+1}^{+\infty} b_{k} \\
\leq \sum_{k=1}^{n_{0}} b_{k} + \sum_{k=1}^{+\infty} b_{k+n_{0}} \\
\leq \sum_{k=1}^{n_{0}} b_{k} + \sum_{k=1}^{+\infty} b_{n_{0}}\cdot (\frac{2}{10})^{k}.
$$
But the last expression is finite because the first term is a finite sum and the second term is a geometric series which is known to be convergent if its argument has modulus less than $1:$

the sum $$ \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}b^{n}=\frac{1}{1-b} $$ provided that $ 0<\vert b \vert < 1.$